# Typing Git status. getting lots of information

Tags: git

When i type `git status` i get lots of information such as `Changes not staged for commit:` and `Untracked files:`. These info are irrelevant right now and in the future.

How do i clear up the information?

---

The question above maybe wasn't really clear to adress my problem. I figured out how to remove `Changes not staged for commit` files by typing `git checkout`. The remaining problem is, I have `Untracked files` that are NOT related to coding. For example my catalog "Pictures" are in `Untracked files`. How do i remove these information?

Answer (score 3):

To remove files from the "Untracked files" list you need to add the relevant patterns to your `.gitignore` file. I.e., if you know all `*.log` files are just temporary files that should never be checked in, add a line `*.log` to the `.gitignore` file.

Another way is to add `--untracked-files=no` command line option to `git status`, but I wouldn't recommend this.